# Is there a calorie-counting iPhone app that knows about UK foods?

Tags: iphone, applications

Are there any calorie-counting/nutrition/exercise-tracking iPhone apps that include significant numbers of foods from popular UK stores (e.g. Tesco, Sainsbury, Waitrose) in their databases, please?

I've tried out MyNetDiary, and it has very few (a couple of dozen or so) items from each of the stores mentioned above.

I've looked at UKPoints, and its UI looks quite primitive.

I've also looked at PureLifeStyle, and the reviews don't sound overly promising. Also, I can't get the demo to work on their website (in IE 9) which doesn't fill me with much confidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the MyFitnessPal app when on my iPhone and I use their website when on my Macbook Pro and find them to be easy to use. They do list the foods you're mentioning on their website here (the list is enormous, look around):

http://www.myfitnesspal.com/brand/list/585

I'm in the USA so make sure they have the foods you want before signing up / buying the iPhone app.

Comment: Thanks very much, especially for the link to the brands page. For [Waitrose](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/nutrition-facts-calories/waitrose), they have 3432 items currently, which is pretty impressive - so I'm marking this as the right answer